# global name 'wd' is not defined in Python

Tags: python, webdriver

I have two scripts. One is funcLib.py, where I defines all the reusable functions, its like :

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

global wd 


def deviceSelection():
    desired_caps = {}
    desired_caps['appium-version'] = '1.0'
    desired_caps['platformName'] = 'iOS'
    desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '8.2'
    desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'iPhone 6'
    desired_caps['app'] = os.path.abspath('/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testapp-sdsdsdfsdf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/testApp.app')  
    wd = webdriver.Remote('http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
    wd.implicitly_wait(60)
    return wd

def fnaccepttermsandconditions():
    time.sleep(5)    
    wd.find_element_by_name("Accept").click()
    time.sleep(5)
```

Here I define all the functions for my automation. Another file is my scripts file, where I call these functions to use in my automation. its called testfile.py

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import datetime
import time
import sys
sys.path.append('/Users/Desktop/iOS/Global Scripts/')
from funcLib import *


wd = deviceSelection();   

def main():
   signin();  


def signin(): 

    try:
        time.sleep(5) 
        fnaccepttermsandconditions()
        time.sleep(5)       

main()
```

Now when I execute testfile.py, It tries to call the function `fnaccepttermsandconditions()` and gets failed with an error message - `global name 'wd' is not defined` I am not sure where I am doing wrong anf I tried my level best also.

Actually going forward I will have many functions in funcLib.py which has to call "**wd**". So in that case how I need to declare wd. Please help

Answer (score 2):

The issue is how you are thinking of globals with python. Remove the line `global wd`, as that should only be used inside a function to denote a variable being used is a global variable.

There are two ways to accomplish what you want, I would suggest not using a global variable at all and just passing the variable as you need it, which is this code below.

Change `fnaccepttermsandconditions` to accept a variable `wd`.

```
def fnaccepttermsandconditions(wd):
    time.sleep(5)    
    wd.find_element_by_name("Accept").click()
    time.sleep(5)
```

And pass it in on `testfile.py`

```
def signin(): 

    try:
        time.sleep(5) 
        fnaccepttermsandconditions(wd)
        time.sleep(5)
```

The other way is to set a global variable to None first, then reference it in your functions.

```
wd = None 


def deviceSelection():
    global wd
    # you could also remove the "return wd" here then as well if making it a global   
    ... 

def fnaccepttermsandconditions():
    global wd
    ...
```

Edit: Also, welcome to Python! Hope you enjoy it, remember you can remove all the ';' from line ends.

Answer (score 1):

As CasualDemon already said: The global will not help you here and I also would recommend that you give the value as a parameter to your function.

One thing as explanation: Global in Python means it is global inside the module context, not inside the program context. So, compared to C it is like a static variable.

Globals that are program-global do not exist in python. You only can take globals from other modules and import them (meaning: import their value!) inside your module context.

Of course, you import the wd variable from your other module -- but by importing you just create a copy of the variable inside your context that is meant for reading and not for writing. By writing to it, you create a new value that will not be available inside the module you imported from.